# GAM with year effect: fixed effects vs random effect, and mgcv:gam(~ s(bs='re') vs gamm4()

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model

I'm trying to identify temporal effects on different response variables (examined in separate models) from data that may have underlaying seasonality and was collected during multiple years (a few consecutive months each year at the same time, not continuous throughout each entire year).

Because of the nonlinear seasonal pattern, my approach was fitting GAMs, but I'm unsure whether I should include year as a fixed parametric effect in a GAM or as a random effect in a GAMM framework, and how to interpret the results (plots) and differences I'm seeing with the different approaches. I'm not very comfortable with mixed models, neither linear and certainly not nonlienar ones.

We have hourly samples between 8:00 and 14:00, hence why using k=7 in the GAM and not bs='cc.

1. `mgcv:gam` with fixed effect

I tested full models that included a `ti(julian, Hour)` term, that were not significant, hence not concluding in my model.

concerns:
a) gam.check remains significant no matter what I do.
b)only 2.16% deviance explained with summary(), not sure how meaningful my results are.

```
mod1<-gam(y ~ s(julian) + s(Hour, k=7) + year, data=dat, method='REML', select=T)

anova(mod1)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(julian) + s(Hour, k = 6) + year

Parametric Terms:
     df     F p-value
year  3 2.961  0.0311

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
            edf Ref.df     F  p-value
s(julian) 4.077  9.000 3.633 7.92e-07
s(Hour)   1.521  5.000 1.662  0.00352

plot(mod1, pages=1, all.terms=T, scale=0)
```

[image: mod1]

2. `mgcv:gam` with random effect

for this response variable, the random effect remains significant, but it changed to not significant for one of the others, while remaining significant when fitting as a parametric fixed effect in gam().

What does the plot tell me? Not sure how to interpret it.

```
mod2<-gam(y ~ s(julian) + s(Hour, k=7) + s(year, bs='re'), data=dat, method='REML', select=T)

anova(mod2)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(julian) + s(Hour, k = 7) + s(year, bs = "re")

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
            edf Ref.df     F  p-value
s(julian) 4.178  9.000 3.697 4.99e-06
s(Hour)   1.550  5.000 1.742   0.0032
s(year)   1.970  3.000 1.939   0.0299

plot(mod2, pages=1, all.terms=T, scale=0)
```

[image: mod2]

3. `gamm4:gamm4` with random effect

no LRT for the random effect, unless I'm missing something. No effects plot.

Larger se?

```
mod3<-gamm4(y ~ s(julian) + s(Hour, k=6), random=~(1| year), data=dat)

anova(mod3$gam)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(julian) + s(Hour, k = 6)

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
            edf Ref.df     F  p-value
s(julian) 4.563  4.563 6.586 1.43e-05
s(Hour)   1.780  1.780 3.742   0.0181

plot(mod3$gam, page=1, scale=0)
```

[image: mod3]

---

I'm also wondering whether I should include the sample date/julian as a random effect rather than as a smoother?

We're not interested in predicting, but trying to understand the hourly patterns. It would be good for us to know whether or not there are seasonal and/or yearly differences, but we're not primarly interested in the patterns of those. We just want to make sure we appropriately account for those when trying to discern the hourly patterns from the pooled data.

I don't have a good handle on when to use such temporal blocking variables as fixed vs. random effects.